# CSS - Making checkbox and long description inline

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a checkbox with some lists. Among that list, one has long description whereas one has short description.

However, one with short description goes inline but other with long description doesn't go.

**Long Descr**

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 30rem;">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Short Descr**

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 30rem;">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it - this uses *flexbox*. Make you container a *flexbox* and prevent the checkbox from auto-adjusting using `flex: 0 0 auto` - see demo below:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 auto; /* ADDED */
}

/* ADDED */
div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 30rem;">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="width: 30rem;">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get rid of inline-block properties for both `<ul>` and `<input>`, and instead just float the checkbox left like this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 30rem;">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
}
.checkwrap {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 30rem;">
  <div class="checkwrap">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ul>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="checkwrap">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ul>
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include something more descriptive than "try it" . A good answer should provide a description of what you have done. Sometimes it is hard to see what has changed in chunk of code. Some comments in the code are also helpful.